# Matching only part of input string using VLOOKUP Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, vlookup, partial

I am having trouble using VLOOKUP to search an array and match part of my input string with a stored column.

This is what I would like:

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFia7.jpg)
[image]

As you can see, my input column strings contains the Strings stored in the 'Stored Data' column. BUT I cannot use wildcards, because the Input is the long string.

For example, this won't work:

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&I3&"*";$H$3:$I$8;1;FALSE)
```

I also don't think I can use LEFT or RIGHT or MID because I don't know where in the Input string the matching string will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the variations that make up your data are not completely covered by your example(s) but I typed them out anyway. The following formula using nested [IFERROR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) functions to return a row number from successive [MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) functions to an [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) function seems to adequately cover your sample data.

```
=INDEX(H:H, IFERROR(MATCH(I3,H:H, 0),
            IFERROR(MATCH(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(I3, " ", REPT(" ", 99)), 99)),H:H, 0),
            IFERROR(MATCH(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(I3, " ", REPT(" ", 99)), 99)),H:H, 0),
            IFERROR(MATCH(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(I3, " ", REPT(" ", 99)), 99, 99)),H:H, 0), NA())))))
```

You can keep the linefeeds if that helps you make sense of the formula. If you have additional situations, you should be able to add additional nested IFERROR(MATCH(... pairs yourself.

[image]

Comment: You will have to change the commas in that formula to semi-colons. I didn't notice that your system uses semi-colons on my first read.

Comment: Hi @Jeeped,    Thanks for the solution!  If I understand this correctly, it is looking for a space either side of the matching string?  So the input string needs a space on either side of it to work.  As you point out, if there are other cases (like ":") I can add additional IFERROR statement.  Not sure if there is any other way around this?

Comment: You may be interested in [Formula to search for a keyword from a keywords list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643008/formula-to-search-for-a-keyword-from-a-keywords-list/36659607#36659607).